# How can change this Javascript to not use global variables?

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble working out how to control program flow and not use global variables with the Javascript in my web app. In this example, when `get_notes()` is called, the ids of the received notes are stored in the `current_note_ids` array. When `add_to_discussion()` is called, `current_note_ids` is sent as a parameter to the server request. How can I do this without having `current_note_ids` as a global variable?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var current_note_ids = [];

    function add_to_discussion(){
        $.post('/add_to_discussion',{current_note_ids:current_note_ids});
    }

    function get_notes(){
        $.post('/get_note_combination',{}, function(data) {            
            current_note_ids = []; // clear existing note details
            for (i in data.notes) {
                current_note_ids.push(data.notes[i].guid);
            }
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#add_to_discussion_button').click(function(){
            add_to_discussion();
            return false;
        });

        $('#get_notes_link').click(function(){
            get_notes();
            return false;
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: I guess you could pass the array as an argument in every one of your functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This removes all that code from the global scope using a [**closure**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

```
(function () {

    var current_note_ids = [];

    function add_to_discussion(){
        $.post('/add_to_discussion',{current_note_ids:current_note_ids});
    }

    function get_notes(){
        $.post('/get_note_combination',{}, function(data) {            
            current_note_ids = []; // clear existing note details
            for (i in data.notes) {
                current_note_ids.push(data.notes[i].guid);
            }
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#add_to_discussion_button').click(function(){
            add_to_discussion();
            return false;
        });

        $('#get_notes_link').click(function(){
            get_notes();
            return false;
        });

    });

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use anonymous function to make it OO-like. In this case, you can choose what to "expose".

```
var notes = $(function() {
    var current_note_ids = [];

    function add_to_discussion() {
        $.post('/add_to_discussion', {
            current_note_ids: current_note_ids
        });
    }

    function get_notes() {
        $.post('/get_note_combination', {}, function(data) {
            current_note_ids = []; // clear existing note details
            for (i in data.notes) {
                current_note_ids.push(data.notes[i].guid);
            }
        })
    }
    return {
        add_to_discussion: add_to_discussion,
        get_notes: get_notes
    };
})();

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#add_to_discussion_button').click(function() {
        notes.add_to_discussion();
        return false;
    });

    $('#get_notes_link').click(function() {
        notes.get_notes();
        return false;
    });

});
```